# CloudFront Pixel Tracker (Simple Version)

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudfront, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to create a very simple pixel down to earth pixel tracking with Cloudfront, mainly taking advantage of the already cool reports the guys from AWS give us with our accounts. These come in .csv for those who don't know and can be downloaded or seen right from their website.

So this is what I have:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // set mobile to desktop
    mobile = "desktop";

    // see if it is mobie
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
        mobile = "mobile";
    }

    // see if it is a bot/crawler
    var botPattern = "(googlebot\/|bot|Googlebot-Mobile)";
    var re = new RegExp(botPattern, 'i');
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent; 

    // if it is, mark it as bot
    if (re.test(userAgent)) {
        var from = encodeURIComponent("bot");
    } else {
        // else, it is a referrer (from where it came from)
        var from = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
    }

    // we create the pixel
    var pixelurl = document.location;
    // var from = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
    var viewport = mobile;
    var uid = Date.now();
    // added a cache bust with Date.now();

    // we create the pixel
    document.getElementById('pixel').src += 
    "?&" + decodeURIComponent(pixelurl) + 
    "&" + decodeURIComponent(from) + 
    "&" + viewport;
    
}, false);
```

It looks for a pixel.png on every page (right at the bottom, before the ) then makes a request with the variables I want to know.

All I need to get from this pixel are the viewport, the referrer page, and the current url.

In the console, I see the request going through:

```
...img/pixel.png?=&http://localhost:1313/featured/?utm_source=internal&http://localhost:1313/=&desktop=
```

But I can't see it in the CloudFront Popular Objects Report. It only shows as `pixel.png`, without any variable, despite me doing the request.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?